# laravel 5.2 Error in Auth

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

i have problem after add Auth controllers in route and see this Error on my browser:

```
InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137:
View [auth.register] not found.
in FileViewFinder.php line 137
at FileViewFinder->findInPaths('auth.register', array('D:\xampp\htdocs\blog\resources\views')) in FileViewFinder.php line 79
at FileViewFinder->find('auth.register') in Factory.php line 165
at Factory->make('auth.register', array(), array()) in helpers.php line 779
at view('auth.register') in RegistersUsers.php line 33
at AuthController->showRegistrationForm() in RegistersUsers.php line 19
at AuthController->getRegister()
```

And my routes.php is :

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
//
Route::get('index','pageController@index');

Route::get('about','PageController@about');
Route::get('contact','PageController@contact');

//Route::get('article','articleController@index');
//Route::get('article/create','articleController@create');
//Route::get('article/{id}','articleController@show');
//Route::post('article','articleController@store');
//Route::get('article/update/{id}','articleController@update');


Route::controller('article','articleController');
//Route::resource('article','articleController');


Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController']);
```

and i clear config too with php artisan config:clear

Comment: you need to create view for registration under folder `auth` with name `register`.  if you dont want to allow user register just remove from auth controller

Comment: i think that laravel has this page default but after i search more i cant see this page ..i create this page now and work fine,thank you

Comment: great to hear that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel 5.2  you can easly call `Route::auth();` 
folow this link [Link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication)
Check wether you have **auth** folders and files in **resource-view** path

then if you want edit yours **AuthenticatesUsers** as your wish

Answer (score 0):

Please create a view under folder `auth` with name `register` or other if you dont want to allow user to register just remove register method from auth controller.